# How can I hide incompatible code from older Python versions?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm writing unit tests for a function that takes both an `*args` and a `**kwargs` argument. A reasonable use-case for this function is using keyword arguments after the `*args` argment, i.e. of the form

```
def f(a, *b, **c):
    print a, b, c

f(1, *(2, 3, 4), keyword=13)
```

Now this only [became legal in Python 2.6](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#other-language-changes); in earlier versions the above line is a syntax error and so won't even compile to byte-code.

**My question is:** *How can I test the functionality provided in the newer Python version and still have the tests run for older Python versions?*

I should point out that the function itself works fine for earlier Python versions, it is only some invocations that are syntax errors before Python 2.6. The various methods I've seen for checking the Python version don't work for this as it doesn't get past the compilation stage.

I would prefer not to have to split the tests into multiple files if at all possible.

Comment: Why not simply reformat the code to be legal in versions prior to 2.6?

Comment: @S.Lott: I guess I didn't appreciate that the new syntax was just syntactic sugar and it could be done differently in earlier versions. If I'd known that it was possible then I wouldn't have asked the question (not everyone is as clever as you :))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think you should be testing whether Python works correctly; instead, focus on testing your own code. In doing so, it is perfectly possible to write the specific invocation in a way that works for all Python versions, namely:

```
f(1, *(2,3,4), **{'keyword':13})
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem. I was too focussed on getting the code I had written to work and didn't realise that the new invocation method had an equivalent in earlier Pythons.

Answer (score 2):

One approach might be to use [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) or [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) along with a test for the current version of Python. This will defer compilation to runtime, where you can control whether compilation actually happens or not.

Comment: I would say using `eval()` is perfectly appropriate for unit test code that may be run on any version of Python.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use such syntax? I mean, this 2.6 feature does not bring any real advantage  other than shortcut.

```
a = [2,3,4]
a.insert(0, 1)
kw = {'keyword'='test'}
f(*a, **kw)
```